# How to send notification to individual user in rails using action cable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

Actually i am bit confuse in action cable . The issue is , i want to send notification to each specific user whose id present in my payment table.And i try  ActionCable.server.broadcast multiple number of times in the controller action . But it shows AbstractController::DoubleRenderError .

### This is my channel

```rb
class WebNotificationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    # stream_from "some_channel"
    stream_from "notifications:#{current_user.id}"
  end
end
```

### Controller Action Part

```rb
@payments = Payment.all
@payments.each do |payment|
  ActionCable.server.broadcast "notifications:#{payment.user_id}", html: notification_render(notification) , count: unseen_notification_number
end
```

note: payment belongs_to user

### Method for render partial

```rb
def notification_render(notification)
  render(partial: 'homepage/notification', locals: {notification: notification})
end
```

### Error track part of console

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DoubleRenderError` is due to the use of `render` in the iterator. I'm not very familiar with Action Cable, but change to `render_to_string` might help.

Comment: Thank you so much @Igor kapkov . render_to_string fix my issue .